# What is the suggested extension for a ProtoBuf payload?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I wonder if there's a Best Practice for naming protobuffs? For the schema we use `something.proto`. What about the payload, the data? I can think of some options:

- `.pbtext`
- `.prototext`

This is important for IDEs to automatically catch up with their schema and do syntax highlighting, for instance, which is why I think it would be a pity to just say `.TXT`.

Comment: "What about the payload, the data?" - usually when talking about protobuf, the binary payload is being used - so: it seems very unlikely that any IDE is going to offer schema support or syntax highlighting - it is *not a human readable protocol*. Unless you mean the JSON format, in which case... well, it is JSON (albeit an opiniated variant), so...

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR It seems like the best accepted answer is `.textproto`.

In VSCode, my extension was automatically recognized by this extension: https://github.com/thejustinwalsh/textproto-grammar . I looked at our internal Company documentation and it seems like `.pbtext` is deprecated in favor of it `.textproto`.